# Contextual popup system API

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Is there a default system API for contextual menus or popup menus such as seen in **OmniFocus**

[image: OmniFocus contextual menus]

or **Apple's** default **iOS apps**

[image: Apple contextual menus]

?

The closest I could find is the `UIPopover`, which doesn't really seem to cover this specialized behavior.. and `UIAction​Sheet` appears to cover a different use case (dialog replacement).

Answer (score 0):

You will not achieve 100 % of this kind of UI using default system API .

If you want to achieve  something like this create on view put button on this  etc.

Make your custom UI

Or else you can take help of [COCOCONTROLS](https://www.cocoacontrols.com)

There are many options available like

[UILabel+Copyable](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/uilabel-copyable)

[HTCopyableLabel](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/htcopyablelabel)

[CopyableCell](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/copyablecell)

Hope it will help you

Comment: Hm... pity! I know about cocoacontrols.com, however custom controls are always prone to break on updates, miss out on new functionality or simply look outdated half a year from now..